# How do we measure the total heat content contained in ocean and atmosphere?

Tags: atmosphere, ocean

This is similar to [How is ocean heat content measured?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-is-ocean-heat-uptake-measured), but here I'm thinking about the total content rather than fluxes in the content between land and ocean.

Comment: 7 years on. I've been attempting to determine this. I used Water at 0C as a reference. Ocean volume is about 3.3E8 cubic miles. Means depth is 3660 m. Temperature of top 200 metres varies from 0-30C with 20C as a rough mean. (This does not make a vast difference). Balance mean is about 4 degrees C. Mean of both layers is about 4.9C - say 5C. Convert to cc ( :-) ) and ue say 4.2 J/cc/K energy gives ~~~~= 2.5 x 10^28 Joule. | All ocean heating since 1970 is typically gives as about 20 x 10^22 Joule so 50 year heating is about 0.001% for whole period.  E&OE :-)

Answer (score 10):

The heat content of a substance is known as [enthalpy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy).  The international convention used for the [Thermodynamic Equation of Sea Water](http://www.teos-10.org/) is maintained by the Joint Committee on the Properties of Seawater.

Equations for calculating the thermodynamic variables of sea water, humid air and other substances are set forth in [**the Numerical implementation and oceanographic application of the thermodynamic potentials of liquid water, water vapour, ice, seawater and humid air – Part 1: Background and equations**](http://www.teos-10.org/pubs/SIA_Paper_1.pdf) by R. Feistel, D. G. Wright,†, D. R. Jackett, K. Miyagawa, J. H. Reissmann, W. Wagner, U. Overhoff, C. Guder
,A. Feistel, and G. M. Marion. *Enthalpy of sea water is discussed in section 4.3.*

One would need temperature, pressure and salinity information for each point in the ocean, and integrate specific enthalpy over the entire volume of the ocean.

Answer (score 2):

Potential enthalpy is the better variable. TEOS-10 functions render the main work as doing the *in situ* measurements. Fortunately, a great amount of that has already been done ([In Search of Ocean Heat](https://blogdredd.blogspot.com/2018/11/in-search-of-ocean-heat.html)).

One converts practical salinity or conductivity into Absolute Salinity, converts temperature into Conservative Temperature, and height (-depth) into Pressure.

Then the TEOS-10 functions can be used with those variables to calculate the requisite forms of enthalpy (specific enthalpy, dynamic enthalpy, potential enthalpy).